# what alternatives do I have to correctly open (for read-only purposes) a docx file?

Tags: libreoffice

I want to know how can I open [this .docx file](http://wiki.whamcloud.com/download/attachments/12127157/Milestone+2-2.3+Solution+Architecture+-+DAOS.docx?version=1&modificationDate=1359672957000) (read-only) in such a way that it looks the same as in SkyDrive or Microsoft Office 2007+

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 amd64. So far I've tried with Google Drive and LibreOffice 4 without any luck.

Comment: Interesting ... Goggle Drive viewer opened this file on my pc Ubuntu 12.10, chromium,

Comment: It opens too on my end, but it's missing the figures and the formatting is completely different than what I see in skydrive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found that I can export to PDF from SkyDrive. This will be the way to go, unless someone else comes up with a better alternative.

Comment: This indeed is the best way I think. Nor Abiword nor LibreOffice correctly (on my computer) correctly open the file.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use [Online Converter](http://www.online-convert.com/), too.

There you can easily upload your docx file and convert it online into pdf / odt.

Comment: I get a 504 error

Comment: when you click on the link above or while converting?

Comment: at that moment, it was when I was clicking on the link. I tried converting the file I linked in my question and it didn't work (document looks different from original).